# Used Phone & No Apple iCloud Password

Tags: iphone, icloud

I was given an iPhone but I don't have the Apple iCloud password.

I don't use as the iPhone as a phone, so no carrier is enabled. I just use it with my home wifi.

A message to enter the old users iCloud password pops up at times.

Any suggestions to make the pop ups for past owners password to stop?

Comment: Where exactly does the password pop up and what does the dialog say (screenshot)? Did you remove all the settings/iCloud logins etc the previous owner has made?

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the iCloud lock to become the rightful owner of the phone. The previous owner should be able to remove the lock using his/her password. Otherwise it is essentially a stolen phone.

Comment: Adding that the original owner can also delete the device from there account by logging in at iCloud.com